# Prefix type operators in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, operators, scala-3

Scala allows writing infix operators for types, just as for expressions:

```scala
type ->[P,Q] = P => Q
```

Making `X -> Y` equivalent to writing `->[X,Y]`.

I would like to have a unary prefix operator, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
type unary_~[P] = ...
```

Writing `~X` causes an error. Of course I can just have `type ~[P] = ...` and then `~[X]` works, but the brackets are not so nice.

Comment: Or just give it a name that will be easier to understand for anyone reading the code? I'm teasing..

Comment: The idea is to write logical formulas using types. To me it seems `~P` would make much more sense than `Negate[P],` particularly in case of complex formulas that would result in deeply nested tree-like structures that are hard to read.
However, the question is not specific to this use case. Someone else might have other good uses for unary type operators, postfix or prefix.